# ubuntu server 14.04 can't get out of tty

Tags: vmware, tty

its been 2 days that I am trying to get out of the tty infterface on ubuntu server14.04 with vmware workstation 9.
I used the sudo apt-get update and udpate ubuntu desktop all successfull but i still can't switch to ubuntu desktop interface , i even use the comman ctrl+altf1 also the start x, but still nothing really I need help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu Server edition by default does not come with a GUI. In Ubuntu 14.04 you can install the Ubuntu desktop after you login in the TTY console using your username and password by running the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends ubuntu-desktop
sudo reboot
```

This command will also install *lightdm*, the Ubuntu default graphical login display manager as a dependency. In order to install a different desktop environment, replace *ubuntu-desktop* in the above command with *xubuntu-desktop*, *lubuntu-desktop* or others.